# Cargo Collective traditional pagination

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

The Cargo Collective developers (those who have contributed developer themes) seem to be enamored of autopagination. As such, I cannot seem able to find a code snippet that will show how to do traditional pagination. Ie. when I set my max number of articles to be "3", it shows only 3 at a time.

I don't mind that I will likely need to provide styles; I just need to know the combination of markup and handlebars required to get the raw pagination in place.

The documentation hints at some "automated" views, but doesn't provide much description of how to use them unless I'm missing something: [views and models documentation](http://cargocollective.com/developers/documentation#views-and-models).

As such, attempts were guesswork. My first such attempt was:

```
<div class="pagination" data-view="Pagination"></div>
```

It seemed like you need a `data-set` to match, but it doesn't seem to indicate which of the data sets populates the Pagination view with useful data.

I tried a few things (no point listing them all as they were trying to catch lightning in a jar attempts) such as the following:

```
<div class="pag_nav" data-view="Pagination" data-set="Navigation">
  {{Navigation}}
</div>
```

I don't think the above makes any particular sense and I didn't have any expectation it would work. Just wanted to illustrate that I tried a few things since I can't find any samples or appropriate documentation.

A point in the right direction for either of those two things would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any way I can actually sandbox with this, or download something to experiment with it? It looks like a closed beta or something...

Comment: It's not a closed beta per se. They try to have a semi-curated approach to the blogs hosted. So it's "by invitation".

Comment: figured it out.. I can't even edit design.handlebars without causing an error, so I can't imagine I'm going to be much use with this I'm afraid!

Comment: Thanks for having a look. :)

Comment: the documentation says you must have an id on your div that has a `data` attribute or else it will not work properly

Comment: Also did you get a simple view to work using this example here: http://cargocollective.com/developers/documentation#views-and-models ? Perhaps start with getting the example to work first?

Comment: Thanks for having a peek, @HieuLe . I hadn't spotted that about the IDs! As for the example, it... sort of... works. The navigation-set is already used successfully elsewhere in the document. When I tried to just copy-paste it, however, it failed. It's a catch-22. I don't know why it failed, so I can't start with getting it to work. Did it fail because there's already a navigation set within an iterator? Is the example wrong? There's not enough documentation on the feature. ;) It does render something templated, just without the {{ url }} populated.

Comment: Adding the ID didn't do anything, alas. Which I'm not surprised about because I don't understand the syntax, options, and templates for the views and models.

Comment: Aww bummer. Is it possible to get any kind of errors that you have?

Comment: Can you link to a working example of how the pagination currently behaves?

Comment: I'd absolutely love to tinker around and try to help, but for whatever reason (and I think it has to be a bug on their side), whatever edit I make to design.handlebars an error is thrown up. Just can't figure it out.

Comment: Virtually all of the current themes will have live samples. They use "infinite scroll" instead of pagination.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like what you are asking for is a [`slideshow`](http://cargocollective.com/slideshow) element.

There is an [article](http://support.cargocollective.com/customer/en/portal/articles/722255-creating-a-front-page-slideshow) on how to do this:

```
{slideshow}{image 1}{image 2}{image 3}{image 4}{/slideshow}
```

And there are also good [support pages](http://support.cargocollective.com/) where you can explore further.

**Update**

All developer templates seems to be bound to Autopagination. See [this discussion](http://support.cargocollective.com/customer/portal/questions/5816565-polaris-project-navigation-pagination), as an example:

> For a design that uses conventional page navigation inside the thumbnail index and text nav, you’ll need to use a Non-Developer Design, like Biblio or Manhattan.

It also gives you tip, which (non-developer) templates to use if you need traditional navigation.

Comment: The title and description both say "traditional pagination". I need a pagination element, not a slideshow.

Comment: Sure, as a user. This is a user who writes a blog and wants to pick a theme with traditional pagination. I am a developer, using a "developer theme" which spawns files that you can freely edit. There are navigation handlebars somewhere; otherwise no theme could use them at all and autonavigation wouldn't need to be put in as handlebars. ;) I appreciate that you wanted to help, but you're barking up the wrong tree. Thanks for taking the time to research, though!